# Getting given value and search for it in DynamoDB using mapper

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

My questions are:

**1) Is there any possible way to get value in DynamoDB table using mapper that is given by user without knowing the id (it's auto generated)?**

**Example:**
User searches for "Karen".

```
**0 | **Owner | **Borrower    
  1 | Jeff    |  Edgar
  2 | Dalgas  |  Karen
  3 | Dixon   |  Michael
  4 | Karen   |  Louise
```

What I want for the output is DynamoDB scans for Karen and give the output like this..

```
**0 | **Owner | **Borrower    
  1 | Dalgas  |  Karen <--------Found Karen in Borrower
  2 | Karen   |  Louise <--------Found Karen in Owner
```

**2) How to get value in DynamoDB such as LIKE in SQL in DynamoDB?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can do this one of two ways.
   - Global Secondary Index
     If this is something you'll be using frequently, it may be wise to add an index to your table on each attribute that you'll be searching through (if multiple items have the same attribute value for the same attribute name in the index, you'll get multiple results)
    - Scan through the table with a FilterExpression: "Borrower = :Karen OR Owner = :Karen"

2) Due the NoSQL nature of DynamoDB,there isn't anything explicitly similar to the pattern matching of "LIKE". However, check out the [Expression Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) to see if you can find something to work around your use case.

Comment: What are the differences between scan and parallel scan? I'm confused.

Comment: They're the same API. However, try to imagine your table as a giant list of keys, 0 - 100.  Scan always starts at 0 and goes through 100, but Parallel Scan allows you to choose a different starting point.  Let's say we choose TotalSegments as 2.  Parallel Scan with segment 1 uninterestingly will start at 0, just like Scan, but will only continue until it reaches the half way point (100 / # of segments).  In practice you won't know your key space, but this allows you to make multiple requests to different parts of your table in "parallel"